# Visual Studio 2008 - Can't make data connections to SQL Server on different subnet

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

I am having an issue where I can't make a data connection to an SQL Server hosted on a different subnet.

SQL Server IP: 192.168.16.15
My IP: 192.168.1.32

I am able to add this server as a server in the Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2008.

I can ping the server fine and the tracert returns

```
Tracing route to mhia02.OFFICE.local [192.168.16.15]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  mhiav202.office.local [192.168.1.9]
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  mhia02.office.local [192.168.16.15]

Trace complete.
```

The SQL Server does allows remote connections.

In Visual Studio 2008 when trying to test the connection it says "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

SQL Server Version: 2008
Server OS: Windows Web Server 2008 R2 64bit
My OS: Windows Vista 64bit

*edit*

Shared Memory, Named Pipes and TCP/IP is enabled in the network configuration settings.

*edit 2*

The issue was that the port 1433 wasn't opened in the firewall.

Comment: maybe your workstation is configured to use shared memory or name pipe to connect to sql server, you can use "Client Configuration Utility" to check this setting.

Comment: Can you telnet to the server on the port that SQL is running on (1433)?  Sometimes a firewall will allow ping, but block the port that SQL listens on...

Comment: @Rambomst Glad that worked... I re-posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to telnet to the server on the port that SQL is running on (1433).  Sometimes a firewall will allow ping, but block the port that SQL listens on.